# Change text language in android

Tags: android

I want to change the language of whole text in android app. And I did this but the problem is where value set in Textview using model class and that point language is not changing.
I really appreciate your help in advance
thanks.

Comment: Are you setting values to the textview directly from model? Show code, how you are setting values.

Comment: It solved digiwizkid Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create two different string.xml files in the format of image given below. The folders for each language values(English created by default) and value-ar(Arabic language in my case)

[image]

and in your layout, you can access the string value for example

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTouchIdLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:letterSpacing="0.05"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:text="@string/touch_id_or_face_id" />
```

that's it's your Text value will be taken from strings.xml directly based on the locale you have selected.

for more information, you can check this link

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Comment: i did same but not happening when I'm changing text using model class

Comment: modal class in the sense you are using MVVM or dagger ??